How to write and deploy nested ARM template
I want to deploy some Azure resources on two resource groups.
Deployment image is like below.

I read some MS reference pages and I will write ARM template like below, but I'm not confidence with it.
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
        "subscriptionID": "0000-000000-0000000",
        "resourceGroup": "resourceGroupA",
        "name": "deploymentResourceGroupA",
        "properties": {
          "mode": "Incremental",
          "template": {
            "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "parameters": {},
            "variables": {},
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices",
                    "dependsOn": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 'storageAcountsName')]"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices",
                    "dependsOn": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 'storageAcountsName')]"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices",
                    "dependsOn": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 'storageAcountsName')]"
                },
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices",
                    "dependsOn": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 'storageAcountsName')]"
                }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
        "name": "deploymentResourceGroupB",
        "properties": {
          "mode": "Incremental",
          "template": {
            "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
            "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
            "parameters": {},
            "variables": {},
            "resources": [
                {
                    "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints",
                    "dependsOn": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', 'storageAcountsName')]"
                }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }

If you know how to write ARM template correctly or how should I do to achieve what I want to do, please tell me your idea.
If you want to more information, please do not hesitate to tell me.

you should probably have a look at bicep. it will generate the nested template for you.

Here is an ARM template with a nested method for creating multiple resources in different resource groups. You can follow the MS Doc for more details about ARM nested.

Note: To create private endpoint with storage account, you need to create multiple resources, follow the private endpoint by using an ARM template and Stack link

{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storagePrefix": {
            "type": "string",
            "maxLength": 11
        },
        "secondResourceGroup": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "SubscriptionID": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "8332bf56-aa7c-4daa-a507-d7e60e5f09a9"
        },
        "secondStorageLocation": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "firstStorageName": "[concat(parameters('storagePrefix'), uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
        "secondStorageName": "[concat(parameters('storagePrefix'), uniqueString(parameters('SubscriptionID'), parameters('secondResourceGroup')))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "[variables('firstStorageName')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS"
            },
            "kind": "StorageV2",
            "properties": {
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices/containers",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('firstStorageName'), '/default/', 'mycontainer')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('firstStorageName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('firstStorageName'), '/default/', 'myfileshare')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('firstStorageName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/tableServices/tables",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('firstStorageName'), '/default/', 'mytable')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('firstStorageName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/queueServices/queues",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "[concat(variables('firstStorageName'), '/default/', 'myqueue')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('firstStorageName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "nestedTemplate",
            "resourceGroup": "[parameters('secondResourceGroup')]",
            "subscriptionId": "[parameters('SubscriptionID')]",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "template": {
                    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "variables": {},
                    "resources": [
                        {
                            "type": "Microsoft.Network/privateDnsZones",
                            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
                            "name": "privatelink-blob-core-windows-net",
                            "location": "[parameters('secondStorageLocation')]",
                            "tags": {
                        "tagName1": "tagValue1",
                        "tagName2": "tagValue2"
                       },
                            "properties": {}
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "parameters": {}
            }
        }
    ]
}

Output:

After executing the ARM template, resources are created in two resource groups.
Resource Group: 1

Resource Group: 2

